# WPF RibbonApplicationMenu: FooterPaneContent & AuxiliaryPaneContent not recognized or not accessible

Tags: wpf, ribbon

Everything works fine in my Ribbon WPF app except for the Footer and Auxiliary panes. I get the following error messages:

- The member "FooterPaneContent" is not recognized or is not accessible.
- The attachable property 'FooterPaneContent' was not found in type 'RibbonApplicationMenu'.
- The member "AuxiliaryPaneContent" is not recognized or is not accessible.
- The attachable property 'AuxiliaryPaneContent' was not found in type 'RibbonApplicationMenu'

I've added `using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;` to the code behind, as well as a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.

Here's my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowMetRibbonControl.WindowMetRibbon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Height="350" Width="525" Icon="images\app48.png" Title="Window met Ribbon">...
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="images\bestand64.png" KeyTip="A">
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="New" Command="New" ImageSource="images\new16.png"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Open" Command="Open" ImageSource="images\open16.png"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Save" Command="Save" ImageSource="images\save16.png"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
                <RibbonSeparator></RibbonSeparator>
                <RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem Header="Afdrukmogelijkheden" ImageSource="images\printer64.png">
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Afdrukken" Command="Print" ImageSource="images\printer64.png"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Afdrukvoorbeeld" Command="PrintPreview" ImageSource="images\preview64.png"></RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
                </RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>
                <RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>
                    <RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>
                        <RibbonButton Command="Close" SmallImageSource="images\close64.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Label="Afsluiten"></RibbonButton>
                    </RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>
                    <RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                        <RibbonGallery Name="MRUGallery" CanUserFilter="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                       SelectionChanged="MRUGallery_SelectionChanged">
                            <RibbonGalleryCategory Name="MRUGalleryCat" Header="Recent Documents">
                            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                        </RibbonGallery>
                    </RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                </RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>       
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>...
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Johan

Comment: I think you are missing  `xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;`

And before `<Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>` add `<ribbon:Ribbon  ....>` and close it on the end.

Comment: No, that doesn't fix it. Btw, I've already added the namespace to the code behind file, which is basically the same thing, right? The odd thing is that most of the Ribbon classes and properties are recognized except for the FooterPaneContent and AuxiliaryPaneContent.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The `<RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>` tag before (and after) FooterPaneContent/AuxiliaryPaneContent is redundant. Silly mistake...